# Android Studio update failed when upgrade to version 1.5

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem to update Android Studio 1.4 to 1.5. After validating installation process update failed and give to me this:

[image: Details problem]

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Android studio and then reinstalling?